# How to select specific field and make total sum for that field with JDO

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I want to make just a simple function that sums all with same name.

I have mapped JDO like this:

```
costName    Cost     
food        10 
food        10
water       5
food        10

total of food 30
total of water 5
```

With this code I get total sum of all (this case 35)

```
int totalsum=0;
int sumCap=0;
for (JDO total : table) {

     totalsum += total.getCost() ;

}
```

How do I get the cost for only food or/and water?

Should be simple but I don't get it.

Comment: While certain JDO implementations support 'group by', GAE does not (AFAIK). See the conversation thread http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/48bef85e84c3f15a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Map<String, Integer> values = new HashMap<>();
for (JDO total : table){
   String name = total.getCostName();
   Integer val = values.get(name);
   if (val == null) val = 0;
   val += total.getCost();
   values.put(name, val);
}
int total = values.get("food");
```

The above calculates all totals in one pass and then allows you to retrieve any you desire. You could also look for a specific name in the loop and only add the values that match.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!!  But can it be done also without HashMap?

Comment: I tried your code but netbeans cannot compile it because of that: "diamond operator is not supported in  -source 1.5 use source 7 or higher" what should I do?

Comment: Can I do some JDO query to select first all where CostName is "food" and then do a for.

Comment: I tried a query like this:                                   List<JDO> costFood = (List<JDO>) pm.newQuery(JDO.class,"capitolo == alimentari").execute();                                              But it gives me the total of all. Unfortunately I HasMap does not wont to work in my .jsp

Comment: I make work your suggestion, I had to take away the <> operator!

Comment: But if there is no entry, of a costName it gives me error server?